# Stuck in infinite loop while traversing an array in C

Tags: c, loops, infinite-loop

I am trying to run this method that is attempting to determine the amount of numbers in an array that are not repeated and when I am traversing the array, I get stuck in an infinite loop. "Hello" is printed infinitely. Why is this happening?

```
// function to determine the amount of non repeated numbers
int nonRepeatedNumbers(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;
    printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
    while(i<size-1){
        printf("%s\n", "HEllo");
        total++;
        if (i = 0)
        {
            if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1])
            {
                total++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1] && arr[i] != arr[i - 1])
            {
                total++;
            }
        }
        i=i+1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", total);
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Consider turning up compiler warnings and taking them seriously. With GCC using the `-Wall` option should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (i = 0)` Sets `i` to 0 each time you hit it. Should be `if (i == 0)`

You could have found this by printing `i` and `size` each time through the loop to see what was going on and why the condition was never met.